# Cant understand the use of After and Wants in this service

Tags: systemd

I was reading mongod.service and saw this:

```
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
```

Shouldn't this be `Before` instead of `After`?

In my understanding the `After` makes `mongod` start after `network-online.target` is started. `Wants` makes `network-online.target` start after `mongod`. I think there is a contradiction here

Comment: Do you really want to start your database server before your network? Without even local& loopback interfaces, what should the server socket bind to?

Answer (score 3):

> In my understand the After make mongod start after network-online.target is started. Wants make network-online.target start after mongod. I think there is a contradiction here

There is no contradiction, because "Wants" and "After" describe different sorts of dependencies.

"After" and "Before" set ordering dependencies -- that is, "mongodb must start after networking".

"Wants" and "Requires" set requirement dependencies -- that is, "if you start mongodb then you should also start networking".

Read the [systemd.unit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for a more detailed discussion of the different sorts of dependencies that can be described in your unit files.

Comment: After reading the man page I understand that wants start network when mongo start , and with after mongo is fully started only after mongo has completed it start . Is this right ? thanks

Comment: I think you have a typo there (you have `mongo` in too many places). If you meant to say, "...and with after, mongo is started only after network-online.target has completed its start", you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've misunderstood what "Wants" means, here it means that mongodb.service wants network-online.target to be started, i.e. it wants the network to be online, much like what the "After=network-online.target" says, under normal circumstances they pretty much say the same.

Comment: `Wants` does not imply an ordering between the two services. With just a `Wants` dependency, you would not be surprised if mongo starts before networking is available.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected.